# How to setup and configure Dart in IIS?

Tags: iis, configuration, installation, dart, flutter

Do you know where I can get information, how to setup IIS in VM, what is minimum requirements (cpu, memory, space etc...) Which OS should I use Win 2012, 2016 etc. And the what is most secure and optimal configuration? Also when I create a Rest API, how to configure user so my Flutter Mobile app securely access it?

Comment: Unfortunately the scope of this question is far too broad for a single answer. Could you review https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic which will help you ask a more specific question.

Comment: Thanks Kev, I will